# Handling datefield in indexes?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset containing some variable1 and a quarterly datefield. I would like to 
`table(variable1)` by datefield. Plus I wonder how to use the datefield in an index like

```
 attach(myds)
 table(variable1[datefield == "1984-01-01"])
```

In SQL I would do Something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM myds GROUP BY YEAR(datefield)
```

but how can I do it in R? I know i could turn it to a character field and strsplit it, but i would prefer to work with real date fields – if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have look at `year` and `round_date` in `lubridate`.

Comment: Thx! Btw : the function is called round_date :)

Comment: Ooops, yeah. Damn inconsistent function names!

Answer (score 0):

Partly I can help myself:

```
format(datefield, "%Y")
```

helps me to get all the years without string splitting. Still I wonder how the rest (quarterly grouping is possible).

lubridate from Hadley is even better than that, because it returns a numeric object.

Still, my problem to find the best way to find the best way to get frequencies by date. 
So far I tried:

```
aggregate(myvar,list(datefield),FUN=table)
```

and ended up with a list like
1984-04-01                                         17, 16, 5, 8, 7, 49

This is okay, but still a little bit cumbersome to process. Let's say myvar is some kind of id and I would like to count the appearance of ids over time. Is there an alternative to looping?